# Why does colors in Tmux's status line look "dim" compared to the shell's prompt?

Tags: shell, terminal, tmux

I use Terminal.app configured as `xterm-256color`. Tmux is configured as:

`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

and Bash is configured with the prompt:

`PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

Why does the colors of the status line look "dim" compared to the colors of the prompt? I've disabled the terminal option "Use bright colours for bold text", so I'd would assume the colors (green and white) to be identical?

```
# status line
set -g status on
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-position bottom 
set -g status-interval 60

set -g status-style fg=white,bg=black
set -g message-style fg=white,bg=black
set -g message-command-style fg=white,bg=black

set -g status-left-length 40
set -g status-left "#[fg=green,bright][#S] "
```

[image]